# when using GUI in Netbeans , I'm trying to call a private void function

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I created Jform windows via Netbeans , i added KeyListener to the class so if someone press LEFT key it will do the same action as clicking on the button. 
but in the keyPressed function i can not call to the button action performed function . how can i do it?

```
    public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame implements KeyListener{
public Main() {
        //Add keyListener to the buutons (the action is defiened in fun keyPressed)

        initComponents();
        jButton1_Computer.addKeyListener(this); 
        jButton1_Student.addKeyListener(this);
    }
.
.
.
 private void jButton1_ComputerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  

        System.out.println("you pressed the button");  
// I want to call to this function from the keyPressed function
    }           


   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
     int keyCode=e.getKeyCode();
     if(keyCode==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){

       jButton1_ComputerActionPerformed(what kind of param should i give here?);
     }

    }
.
.
    }
```

Comment: You don't have an ActionEvent there, so it's no use calling that method there. Create a second method, which does not take parameters, and is called from within your current menthod, and from within the method you think to call now.

Comment: but the ' jButton1_ComputerActionPerformed' function must have an argument , so what kind of param should i use?

Comment: again, you're not supposed to call that method there. It takes an argument of type ActionEvent, which you don't have there. Put the code that is currently in that method, in a new method, and call that method. Also call that method from within jButton1_ComputerActionPerformed

Answer (score 1):

Don't call the "ActionListener", instead, call `doClick()` on the button which will press the button, and that will call the JButton's ActionListener for you.

```
jButton1.doClick();
```

Also you will want to avoid using KeyListener for this and instead use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you add KeyListener to button

```
myButton.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {

        }
    });
```